# FindDistributionParameter slow with user defined Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I am trying to define my own probability distributions in order to fit data using Maximum Likelyhood. To test my distributions, I have produce a set of data Normally distributed using

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 10^3]
```

defined my own Normal Distribution and fit it to data:

```
testDistribution[a_, b_] := ProbabilityDistribution[E^(-((x - a)^2/(2 b^2)))/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] b), {x, -Infinity, Infinity},Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals && b > 0]
params = FindDistributionParameters[data, testDistribution[a, b],  ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

which gave the results {a -> 0.029678, b -> 1.99852} in 10.39 seconds

However, using the following line

```
params = FindDistributionParameters[data, NormalDistribution[a, b], ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
```

gave {a -> 0.0296781, b -> 1.99852}but in only 0.03 seconds. So it looks like my user defined distribution is not properly defined. This makes a large difference when I increase the size of the data.

Does anybody knows where the difference come from?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)

$HistoryLength = 0; (* to make timings fair *)

RandomSeed[1]; (* repeatable random data *)

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 10^3];

testDistribution[a_, b_] :=
 ProbabilityDistribution[
  E^(-((x - a)^2/(2 b^2)))/(Sqrt[2 π] b),
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals && b > 0]
```

`"MaximumLikelihood"` is the default setting for the option `ParameterEstimator`

```
Options[FindDistributionParameters, ParameterEstimator]

(*  {ParameterEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"}  *)

params = FindDistributionParameters[
   data, testDistribution[a, b]] //
  AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.530307, {a -> -0.00916218, b -> 2.01538}}  *)
```

If this took 10 seconds there is something else going on. Perhaps you should try restarting Mathematica or restarting your operating system.

```
params2 = FindDistributionParameters[
   data, NormalDistribution[a, b]] //
  AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000771, {a -> -0.00916218, b -> 2.01538}}  *)
```

The built-in distributions are much faster, presumably their code is highly optimized

It is even faster to not specify a distribution than define your own.

```
Thread[{a, b} -> List @@ FindDistribution[data]] //
 AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.344109, {a -> -0.00916218, b -> 2.01538}}  *)
```